# Change TimePicker Size in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net, resize, timepicker

I have a timepicker installed in ASP.NET. It's working just fine but I'm a little bit bothered by its display. I am trying to change its size by

1. changing Height and Width
2. adding CSS attribute

But none of them seem to work.

This is my mark-up:

```
 <MKB:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False"
  style="margin-bottom: 0px" AmPm="PM" BorderColor="Silver" Date="" Hour="0" 
  Minute="0" Second="0" SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve" Height="26px" Width="137px">
  </MKB:TimeSelector>
```

This is how it looks whatever the value of Height and Width is:

[image]

Is it even possible to change its size? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timepicker is only a bunch of inputs, so wrap it into the div or any other element and add styling.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="something"><MKB:TimeSelector></MKB:TimeSelector></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.something input {
    /*your styling*/
}
```

Comment: I tried adding css (with Height, Width, Fontsize, Padding and Margin) but the display is still the same. I also tried the same with div style.

Comment: For the height and width use `!important` in css as otherwise it won't override the inline styles, but padding and margin should work as intended.